# A prime number divides only the numerator

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that there is a prime number $q$ which divides the numerator of $\frac{x^{\ell e}-1}{(x^{\ell}-1)(x^{e}-1)}$ and doesn't divide the denominator. Here, $\ell,e,x$ are integers, and $x$ is of the form $p_1^{p_2^{\ell-1}}\cdot p_2^{p_1^{e-1}}$, where $p_1,p_2$ are primes distinct from $q$, and $\ell =p_1$, $e=p_2$.

- Forgot something important: $\ell e>\ell+e$.

Attempt:
I have tried using the next sentence to make it easier for me:
$$(x^{\ell}-1,x^{e}-1)=x^{(\ell,e)}-1$$ Since $(\ell,e)=1,$ we get: $(x^{\ell}-1,x^{e}-1)=x^{(\ell,e)}-1=x-1$.
To prove that there is a prime $q$ divides only the numerator, we shall check whether the number $\frac{x^{\ell e}-1}{(x^{\ell}-1)(x^{e}-1)}$ is integer, and after division of the numerator by the denominator, there is $q$ in the factorization.

Without any success from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Got it done. This what I could do, since this is my question.

Comment: When $e=\ell=1$, it doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @user8268. Another counter-example: $l=2, e=3, x=2.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet however $x$ cannot be 2.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Note that I added something important. I am sorry that I missed adding this detail.

Comment: @user8268 Note that I added something important. I am sorry that I missed adding this detail.

Comment: Why do you say that $x$ can't be $2$? There is nothing to prevent that in your question, as far as I can see.

Comment: @TonyK see the definition of $x$... $$x=p_1^{p_2^{\ell}}\cdot p_2^{p_1^{e}}$$

Comment: I have made an edit, to clarify this. You can revert it if you like.

Comment: @TonyK I will leave it. Thank you! I can see why some people may find it unclarified.

Comment: @lulu maybe you can help?

Comment: @Tanner maybe you can help?

Comment: @Robert Israel can you help?

Comment: @Peter can you help?

Comment: @Ross Milikan can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write:

$$\frac{N=(x^l)^e-1}{D=(x^l-1)(x^e-1)}=\frac{(x^l)^{e-1}+(x^l)^{e-2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +1}{x^e-1}$$

If $e=2k$ is even then:

$x^l+1|(x^l)^{e-1}+(x^l)^{e-2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +1$

Therefore:

$x^l+1|N$

Also we have:

$D=x^e-1=(x^k-1)(x^k+1)$

If $l\neq k=\frac e2$ then $x^l+1$ divides N but does not divide D.So $x^l+1$ must be primes .For example for $l=2$ and  $x=2$ gives $q=5$ so if e=6 , for instance, we get:

$D=(2^2-1)(2^6-1)=189$

$N=2^{12}-1=4095$.

The fraction is symmetric for and l and e so we may change e with l in above argument; the condition is:

$L\neq \frac e2$

Or:

$e\neq \frac l2$

That is one of l or e must be even.

Update:

Suppose e and l are odd, then it is possible to have a prime satisfying the condition for example for x=2, l=3, e=5 we get:

$\frac ND=\frac{2^{15}-1}{(2^3-1)(2^5-1)}=\frac{151}{7\cdot 31}$

So prime we are looking for is $151$.

Also for certain values of x, e and l, the numerator my be divisible by denominator. The condition must be discussed in separate question. For example for x=2,l=2, e=5 we get:

$\frac ND=31$

So 31 divides numerator.

Or with x=3, l=2 and e=5 we get:

$\frac ND=4 \times 61$

That means prime 61 only divides the numerator.

Comment: Why $x^{l}+1$ doesn't divide $D$, and what $D$ do you refer to? because I see there is D twice in your explanation .

Comment: @anonymous1213, $x^l+1 \neq x^k+1$ because $l\neqk$ .Also $x^l+1$ does not divide  $x^k-1$, therefore $x^l+1$ does not divide D. I edited the answer.

Comment: But what if $e$ is odd?

Comment: @anonymous1213, then you can not construct a prime as per required condition.

Comment: It means that it's not true for an odd $e$? or you cannot apply what you have said again? if so I will be glad to see how you can prove that for an odd $e$. I think that the claim is true for an odd $e$.

Comment: @anonymous1213, OK I will think about it and let you know the result.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry for asking... Did you think about that?

Comment: @anonymous1213, Yes , see the edit.

Comment: First of all thank you! Secondly, is there a more general way to explain that? because I can't see how you have showed that the existed prime divides the numerator and doesn't divide the denominator.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you, but I fixed some important details of what are $x$, $\ell$ and $e$. I haven't noticed that I forgot writing this. Can you now think why when $\ell$ or $e$ are odd this hold? I really am sorry!

Comment: @anonymous1213, there may be  a general way in advanced number theory.I am sure you find the reason for e and l odd, but I will try more.

Comment: Can you do that?

Comment: @anonymous1213, I dont' think so. I hope a member of this site who is professional in number theory do that.

Comment: I need to know by today. Do you know any professional in number theory? So I can tag them? because I am new to this site.

Comment: @anonymous1213, May be these users: Tanner, Robert Israel, Peter, Ross Milikan...